# What's wrong with this program in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I'm writing a program that receive a character and numbers of line and display it,its write with function but have some error and I don't now why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void chap(char,int,int);
int mian()
{
    int x,z,q;
    char y;
    cout<<"do you want run program?";
    cin>>x;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        cout<<"enter your character: \n";
        cin>>y;
        cout<<"\nenter the number of lines: \n";
        cin>>z;
        cout<<"enter 1 for normal pattern and enter 0 for unnormal pattern : \n";
        cin>>q;
        cout<< chap(y,z,q);
        cout<<"do you want run program?";
        cin>>x;
    }
}

void chap(char y,int z,int q)
{
    if(q==1)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<z;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    cout<<y;
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
        if(q==0)
        {
            for(int i=z;i!=0;i--)
            {
                for(int j=i;j<=i;j--)
                {
                    cout<< y;
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
}
```

At compile time I receive this error message:

> E:\c++test++\test1\main.cpp|18|error: no match for 'operator<<' in
>   'std::cout << chap(((int)y), z, q)'| –

If I were able to compile and run the program, this is the desired behavior: you enter character = p line = 5 and it shows you:

```
p
pp
ppp
pppp
ppppp
```

Comment: "but have some error and i dont now whay".  You should tell us what the error/problem is.

Comment: its not run any way and i dont know whay,and this is the question!

Comment: I would start by renaming mian() to main()....

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: cout<< chap(y,z,q); what do you expect this does?? clue: chap returns nothing!

Comment: @decltype_auto Whay should he ? Its not run any way ! ;-)

Comment: the error is E:\c++test++\test1\main.cpp|18|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << chap(((int)y), z, q)'|

Comment: remove  
cout<< chap(y,z,q); and just call chap(y,z,q);

Comment: please help me i am a amatur in c++ and i want ro write it with function but its not good,

Comment: @Djkaso Please put such additional information in your question, not in comments. You might want to read about how to write a [MCVE].

Comment: thanks soo much @Nandu its run!

Comment: sorry i just now register in site i i dont know how to write my question.

Comment: @Djkaso There's a lot of information you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the helpcenter.

Comment: @Djkaso Have a look at the two edits made, this will give you an idea how a good question does look like. And if you can spare the time have a look at the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help and take the tour.

Comment: @Marged: mybook::not_run<Any>::whay ? "" : "";

Comment: @decltype_auto That's whay too complicated for me ;-)

Comment: @Marged jou mhay resonidder tat.

Comment: great. check this one out:   for(int j=i;j<=i;j--)  {  cout<< y;  } - i think this might be an infinite loop

Comment: yes @Nandu thanks so much you very help me

Comment: @Djkaso `int mian()` are you serious? Post real code please!! Or even better stay off from this site. We have quality standards for questions posted here!

Comment: @Djkaso Also consider reading a book or good tutorials, as recently recommended. Just saying _I don't want to_ makes your questions legit here.  Stack Overflow isn't the right place nannying you through the basics. The track you are currently on, will get you quickly being banned asking any more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void chap(char,int,int);
int main()
{
int x,z,q;
char y;
cout<<"do you want run program?";
cin>>x;
while(x!=0)
{
    cout<<"enter your character: \n";
    cin>>y;
    cout<<"\nenter the number of lines: \n";
    cin>>z;
    cout<<"enter 1 for normal pattern and enter 0 for unnormal pattern : \n";
    cin>>q;
    chap(y,z,q);
    cout<<"do you want run program?";
    cin>>x;
  }
}

void chap(char y,int z,int q)
{
if(q==1)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<z;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                cout<<y;
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
    if(q==0)
    {
        for(int i=z;i>0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                cout<< y;
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
 }
```